# Excel macro enabled worksheet gives error upon saving

Tags: excel, popup, vba

I am currently working in developing a managing tool that is intended to be use by the whole office in the day to day management. This excel-based tool is a multiple sheet workbook in which several actions can be carried out automatically (using *Private Sub Worksheet_Change*) or through specific buttons.

In particular one of the purposes is to create automatically, once I enter an activity description, a validation list of the running projects (parametric) which are saved in another sheet. Even if the code seems to work smoothly, every time I save and close the worksheet the following error pop-up:
[Excel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XFLs.png).
It seems similar to another problem that I face in another sheet ("Calendar") in which again the code has to perform a similar task changing the validation on the cell next to the one in which the project has been inserted.

Basically it seems that the problem is mainly caused by this parametric validation list but I am not able to found exactly where. Can you support?

Here attached you can find the code for the two sheets:

### Week

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'On Error GoTo exitsub
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws_proj_port As Worksheet
Dim ws_act_cat As Worksheet
Dim ws_curr_week As Worksheet
Dim ws_cal As Worksheet
Dim ws_graph As Chart
Dim proj_type As String
Dim act_proj_arr(100) As String
Dim act_proj_val As String
Dim lastrow_act As Integer
Dim hrs_done As Double
Dim hrs_day As Double
Dim hrs_week As Double
Dim hrs_marker As Double


Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim r As Integer


Set ws_curr_week = ActiveSheet
Set ws_proj_port = Sheets("Projects portfolio")
Set ws_act_cat = Sheets("Activity categories")
Set ws_cal = Sheets("Calendar")


proj_type = ""
proj_color = ""
proj_name = ""
act_cat = ""
act_cat_j = ""
proj_imp = ""

If Target.row > 2 And Target.row < 34 And Target.Column < 16 Then
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).Value = "- to be selected -"

            '------- START project validation list creation
            ws_curr_week.Activate
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).Validation.Delete
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).Select
            With Selection.Validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=week_proj"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
            End With
            '----- END project validation list creation
        Else
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).ClearContents
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).Validation.Delete
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 2).ClearContents
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 2).Validation.Delete
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, 7).ClearContents
        End If
    ElseIf Target.Column = 2 Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
        '------- START activity validation list creation
            ws_proj_port.Activate
            ws_proj_port.Range("A2").Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            r = ActiveCell.row
            proj_matrix = "A2:H" & r
            proj_name = ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Value
            proj_type = Application.VLookup(proj_name, ws_proj_port.Range(proj_matrix), 2, False)
            proj_color = Application.VLookup(proj_name, ws_proj_port.Range(proj_matrix), 3, False)

            ws_act_cat.Activate
            ws_act_cat.Range("D2").Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            lastrow_act = ActiveCell.row
            j = 0
            i = 2

            If proj_type = "Linework" Then
                For i = 2 To lastrow_act
                    If ws_act_cat.Cells(i, 1).Value = proj_type And ws_act_cat.Cells(i, 2).Value = proj_name Then
                        act_proj_arr(j) = ws_act_cat.Cells(i, 4).Value
                        j = j + 1
                    End If
                Next i
            Else
                For i = 2 To lastrow_act
                    If ws_act_cat.Cells(i, 1).Value = proj_type Then
                        act_proj_arr(j) = ws_act_cat.Cells(i, 4).Value
                        j = j + 1
                    End If
                Next i
            End If

            act_proj_val = Join(act_proj_arr, ",")

            ws_curr_week.Activate
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).Value = "- to be selected -"
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).Validation.Delete
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).Select
            With Selection.Validation
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=act_proj_val
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
            '------- END activity validation list creation

            'Set Importance Y/N
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, 7).Value = Application.VLookup(proj_name, ws_proj_port.Range(proj_matrix), 7, False)
        Else
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, 7).ClearContents
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).ClearContents
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).Validation.Delete
        End If
    ElseIf Target.Column = 10 Or Target.Column = 11 Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, 12).Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm", vbMonday, vbFirstJan1)
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, 13).Value = Application.Text(Date, "[$-809]dddd")
        Else
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, 12).ClearContents
            ws_curr_week.Cells(Target.row, 13).ClearContents
        End If
        calc_hrs hrs_done, hrs_day, hrs_week, hrs_marker
        create_graph hrs_done, hrs_day, hrs_week, hrs_marker
    ElseIf Target.Column = 4 And ws_curr_week.Range("P2") <> "Sunday" And ws_curr_week.Range("P2") <> "Saturday" And ws_curr_week.Range("P2") <> "Monday" Then
        calc_hrs hrs_done, hrs_day, hrs_week, hrs_marker
        create_graph hrs_done, hrs_day, hrs_week, hrs_marker
    End If
End If

Target.Cells.Select
exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

### Calendar

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'On Error GoTo exitsub
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws_proj_port As Worksheet
Dim ws_act_cat As Worksheet
Dim ws_cal As Worksheet
Dim ws_hid As Worksheet
Dim act_proj_arr(100) As String
Dim act_proj_val As String
Dim proj_name As String
Dim last_proj As Integer


Set ws_proj_port = Sheets("Projects portfolio")
Set ws_act_cat = Sheets("Activity categories")
Set ws_cal = Sheets("Calendar")
Set ws_hid = Sheets("Hidden")

If Target.Column > 2 And Target.Column < 14 And Target.row < 16 Then
    If Target.Column Mod 2 <> 0 Then
        If Target.Value = "-" Then
            ws_cal.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).Value = "-"

            ws_cal.Range(Cells(Target.row, Target.Column), Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1)).Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
                .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

            With Selection.Font
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With

            With Selection
                .Font.Bold = True
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            ws_cal.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Select

        ElseIf Target.Value = "Lunch" Then
            ws_cal.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).ClearContents
            ws_cal.Range(Cells(Target.row, Target.Column), Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1)).Select
            With Selection
                .Style = "Accent2"
                .Font.Bold = True
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With


        ElseIf Target.Value <> "" Then
            '------- START formatting
            proj_name = ws_cal.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Value
            ws_proj_port.Activate
            ws_proj_port.Range("A2").Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            last_proj = ActiveCell.row
            proj_arr = ws_proj_port.Range("A1:A" & last_proj)
            proj_row = Application.Match(proj_name, proj_arr, 0)
            ws_proj_port.Activate
            ws_proj_port.Range("H" & proj_row).Select
            Selection.Copy

            ws_cal.Activate
            ws_cal.Range(Cells(Target.row, Target.Column), Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            ws_cal.Range(Cells(Target.row, Target.Column), Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1)).Interior.Color = ws_proj_port.Range("H" & proj_row).Interior.Color
            ws_cal.Range(Cells(Target.row, Target.Column), Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1)).WrapText = True


            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            '------- END formatting


            '------- START activity validation list creation
                ws_proj_port.Activate
                ws_proj_port.Range("A2").Select
                Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                r = ActiveCell.row
                proj_matrix = "A2:H" & r
                proj_name = ws_cal.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Value
                proj_type = Application.VLookup(proj_name, ws_proj_port.Range(proj_matrix), 2, False)
                proj_color = Application.VLookup(proj_name, ws_proj_port.Range(proj_matrix), 3, False)

                ws_act_cat.Activate
                ws_act_cat.Range("D2").Select
                Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                lastrow_act = ActiveCell.row

                j = 0
                i = 2

                If proj_type = "Linework" Then
                    For i = 2 To lastrow_act
                        If ws_act_cat.Cells(i, 1).Value = proj_type And ws_act_cat.Cells(i, 2).Value = proj_name Then
                            act_proj_arr(j) = ws_act_cat.Cells(i, 4).Value
                            j = j + 1
                            Else
                        End If
                    Next i
                    Else
                    For i = 2 To lastrow_act
                        If ws_act_cat.Cells(i, 1).Value = proj_type Then
                            act_proj_arr(j) = ws_act_cat.Cells(i, 4).Value
                            j = j + 1
                            Else
                        End If
                    Next i
                End If

                act_proj_val = Join(act_proj_arr, ",")

                ws_cal.Activate
                ws_cal.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).Value = "- to be selected -"
                ws_cal.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).Validation.Delete
                ws_cal.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).Select
                With Selection.Validation
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=act_proj_val
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
                End With
                '------- END activity validation list creation

                Else
                ws_cal.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Select
                Call cell_cal_format
                ws_cal.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).ClearContents
                ws_cal.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).Validation.Delete
                ws_cal.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column + 1).Select
                Call cell_cal_format
                ws_cal.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Select
        End If
    End If
End If

exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub cell_cal_format()
Selection.Style = "Normal"
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Alessio

Comment: what error and where

Comment: The error is coming after I re-open the excel file. I use the sheet, the validation list is automatically generating correctly, I save and close. When I open it again the error popup shared in the post is coming out messing the existing format and removing the macro from the sheets affected.